# JSF Multiple components in grid

Tags: jsf, jstl, facelets, composite-component, jsf-1.2

I am trying to get the reusable group of jsf 1.2 components inside a panelgrid using Facelet tag file. @Balusc's previous answer at [How to make a grid of JSF composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component) was a fabulous resource. I have a couple of followup questions:

1. In my c:when how do I test for the tagName itself instead of checking for the attributes. Instead of

   ```
   <c:when test="#{type != 'submit'}">
   ```

I want to check tagName itself to decide how to format it. If 'input' do xxx.

2 Is this approach is still valid with jsf 1.2 other than f:ajax? If yes, can I replace with a4j:support...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *In my c:when how do I test for the tagName itself instead of checking for the attributes.*

I'm not sure how this question makes sense. It sounds like that you're approaching something not entirely right. Do you maybe have copypasted exactly the same piece of code over multiple tag files? You should not do that. Make it a reuseable `<ui:composition>` or maybe `<ui:decoration>` instead which you compose/decorate in every tag file along with a fixed and unique `<ui:param>` value depending on the taglib file.

---

> *Is this approach is still valid with jsf 1.2 other than f:ajax? If yes, can I replace with a4j:support...?*

Being able to create tag files is not necessarily specific to JSF, but to the view technology used, which is in this case Facelets. You can even do similar stuff in its predecesor JSP, see also this answer for an example: [JSF 1.2 custom component from jsp:include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435367/jsf-1-2-custom-component-from-jspinclude/9441652#9441652) It should work just fine in every JSF version supporting the view technology in question.

As to ajax support, it doesn't matter to the tag file what you're all doing inside the tag file. If you want and can use `<a4j:support>` then just do it.

Comment: My idea was to use a universal tag file for all my components. Hence I needed to identify the tagNames and determine what need to be rendered for each component. Like you said, maybe its not the right approach.

Comment: Then define common tag body content with another template and reference it by `<ui:composition>` or `<ui:decorate>`.

Comment: Thanks @Balusc. I have branched another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284935/multiple-jsf-components-inside-a-panelgrid related to this if you can help me with.