# How to create a composite component using JSP?

Tags: jsp, jsf, composite-component

I am trying to create a composite component in JSF and I want the file type as `.jspf` instead of `.xhtml` and all the examples I came across online are XHTML. I was just curious whether we can write composite component using JSP or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible. A [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) is specific to the [Facelets 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info) view technology (or "XHTML", as you incorrectly overgenerified it). Facelets is basically the [successor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) of the legacy JSP view technology. JSP is been **deprecated** as view technology since JSF 2.0.

In JSP, closest what you can get to achieve this is a [tag file](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html). See also this answer for a concrete example: [JSF 1.2 custom component from jsp:include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435367/jsf-1-2-custom-component-from-jspinclude/9441652#9441652).

Or better, just [migrate to Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870). It offers [so much more templating advantages over JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269).

Comment: can I use facelets in jsf 1.2??

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer with lots of useful links thanks !! :)

Comment: Yes, you can use [Facelets 1.x](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html) (beware this tutorial is outdated and might contain broken links!). But composite components are introduced in Facelets 2.0 and not available in Facelets 1.x, so you can't use it in JSF 1.2 anyway. A tag file is really the best what you can get in JSF 1.2.